# Efficient SVD of a matrix without some of the columns

Tags: matrices, computer-science, matrix-analysis, computer-algebra

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$ of rank $r$ and its SVD decomposition, i.e,
$$
A = U S V^\top,
$$
where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times r}$ and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times r}$ are orthonormal, $S = \mathrm{diag}\left(s_1, \dots, s_r\right)$, and $s_i \in \mathbb{R}$. I would like to compute SVD for $B = [A_{i_1}, \dots, A_{i_k}] \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times k}$, and $k \leq r$, i.e., for a matrix that consists of a full rank selection of columns from $A$.

If SVD is straightforwardly applied to $B$, then the time complexity would be $\mathcal{O}(pk\min(p,k))$. Can I do that more efficiently?

**Note:**

- If you consider the the right singular vectors of $A$, column selection effectively leads to projecting these to a subspace in the canonical basis. Projection does not preserve the angles between the vectors, and hence one cannot do better than just re-doing the SVD on $B$.
- However, does there exist a rotation of the $V$ singular vectors that preserves the angles and it could be done more efficiently than just running SVD on $B$?

Comment: If $B$ is just a selection of columns of $A$, why not simply multiplying $V^T$ with a permutation matrix which is truncated

Comment: Unfortunately, truncation of the column space does not lead to a valid decomposition of matrix $B$. It basically projects the original matrix $A$ onto the preserved column subspace. This does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I managed to find a reasonable answer. The operation is called updating (in case of adding new columns to the original matrix) or donwdating (in case of removing) of the SVD. Full update/downdate of SVD with a single column can be done in $\mathcal{O}\left(r^2(1 + p + q)\right)$ time [[1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379505003812)].
Such modifications of SVD can be also parallelized.

Here are a few links to papers that deal with this problem:

1. [Fast low-rank modifications of the thin singular value decomposition](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379505003812)
2. [A stable and fast algorithm for updating the singular value decomposition](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr966.pdf)
3. [A fast and stable algorithm for downdating the singular value decomposition](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122114004568)

Comment: There is something fishy in your computational complexity. How can adding columns be $O(r^2)$ when reading the input (the column vector to add) may contain alone more than $r^2$ entries?

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. I double checked and it's indeed $O(r^2 + p + q)$ given that all the data is already in memory. The $O(p + q)$ term comes from a couple of vector-to-matrix multiplications.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $O(r(p+q+r))$? That would make more sense to me, since I'd expect that you have to project your new column $x$ on the reduced $r$-dimensional space with something like $U^Tx$.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, there are matrix-matrix multiplications ($p \times r$ and  $q \times r$ with $r \times r$) that are necessary to construct new orthonormal subspace matrices. If one wants to update singular values only, you are right, the time complexity would be $O(r(p+q+r))$.